# Find area bounded by the curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, area

If $y=f(x)$ is solution of differential equation $ydx+dy= {-e^{x}}{y^2}dy$  with $y(0)=1$

find the area bounded by curves: 
$y=e^{x}$,$y=f(x)$&$x=1$

My attempt : since given differential equation is not exact, hence I find it, in fact this is $$u(x,y)=\dfrac{e^{-x}}{y^2}$$
And its solution is : $$y^2=e^{-x}$$
Without seeing their graphs, I have no idea, how to find it. Please give your valuable hints. 
Also easy way to find solution of differential equation. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have no idea how to find the area?

Comment: @TobyMak here I have no idea because my all ideas have failed already.

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^x$ is positive for all real $x$, you can discard the negative solution of $y^2=e^{-x}$ which leaves you with $y = \sqrt{e^{-x}}$. Furthermore, $e^x$ and your differential equation meet at $x=0$ since $y(0)= 1$ and $e^0 = 1$.

So you have to find:

$$\int_0^1 e^x - \sqrt{e^{-x}} \ \mathrm{d} x$$

Comment: Please give me reasoning, why did you subtract $\sqrt{e^{-x}}$ from $e^{x}$ ?

Comment: $e^x$ is the top curve, and $\sqrt{e^{-x}}$ is the bottom curve, and to find the integral you integrate top curve - bottom curve. It seems to me that you need to review and practice the fundamentals of calculus (Calculus I content). If you have any more questions, please ask a new question.